# OpenCL pixel check

Tags: computer-vision, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I have a opencl kernel that does some warping on an images. This is a forward mapping and each kernel instance handles the mapping/warpping of one pixel in the source image. This means that some kernel instances (pixels in the source image) map to the same destination pixel. This means that i have no control over what value is written to those pixels in the destination image. They just get the value of the kernel instance that executes the write command last. Is there a way to do a check if i am writing to a location (pixel) that has already been written to? I have a depth map of the image i am warping and ideally i would like to write the frontmost pixel if more pixels map to the same location, is this possible?

```
__kernel void dwarpIntThree(__read_only image2d_t src,
        __read_only image2d_t dispmap,
        float T,
        __write_only image2d_t dst,
        sampler_t sampler,
        int dmin, int dmax,
        sampler_t sampler_1, float posx, float posy
                    ){
int2 srcCoords = (int2)( get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));

if ((srcCoords.x >= get_image_width(dst)) | (srcCoords.y >= get_image_height(dst)))
    return;

float true_depth = round((read_imagef(dispmap, sampler, srcCoords).x)*(dmax-dmin)+dmin);

int2 uv;
uv.x = srcCoords.x-true_depth*(posx/T);
uv.y = srcCoords.y-true_depth*(posy/T);

if ((uv.x >= get_image_width(dst)) || (uv.y >=get_image_height(dst))| (uv.x < 0) | (uv.y < 0)){
    return;}

float4 srcPixel = read_imagef(src, sampler, srcCoords);

write_imagef(dst, uv, srcPixel);
}
```

So what i want to do is to only write_imagef the current pixel in src to the coordinate uv in dst, if it has a depth smaller than a possible pixel from src which also maps to uv. But i dont know if it is possible to check that since the kernels of course execute concurrently.

Comment: Can you share some of the code?

Comment: If they are wiriting to same destination, are they serial then?

Comment: No the code shown is executed in parallel for each pixel in the src image. And the problem is that more pixels can be mapped to the same uv coordinates in the dst image.

Comment: You want to calculate several things things then write in an order to same pixel?

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult. For one, the output image is write-only. And if you use a read-write buffer instead, then you have contention between work items. Atomic operations can solve this, but are slow.

Is it possible to re-architect to use reverse-mapping instead? You'd have to change what the depth map represents.

I think using OpenGL and leveraging depth buffers would be a better fit.